# Join Multiple Tables to a Single Table without CTEs or Row_Number in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 4 tables. Table A is (all the) IDs, Table B, Table C, and Table D contain different data. All the tables have only the ID columns in common. The sample data is given in picture_1.

[image]

I want to get the output like that show in picture_2.

[image]

My limitations are that I am using MySQL 5.6.10. Therefore I cannot use CTEs or Row_number(), or any other features which were introduced post the MySQL 5.6.10 version.
I tried the below code but it gave errors as there were multiple duplicate rows.

```
select a.id,b.name,b.state,c.subject,c.marks,d.sports,d.matches
from table_a as a
left join table_b as b on b.id = a.id
left join table_c as c on c.id = a.id
left join table_d as d on d.id = a.id
```

Comment: You mean to say group by subject and sports?

Comment: Why the values taken from tables 3 and 4 are combined into one row for id=1 and not for all another rows?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
( select id,b.name,b.state,NULL subject,NULL marks,NULL sports,NULL matches
  from table_a as a
  left join table_b as b USING (id) )
UNION 
( select id,NULL,NULL,c.subject,c.marks,NULL,NULL
  from table_a as a
  left join table_c as c USING (id) )
UNION 
( select id,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,d.sports,d.matches
  from table_a as a
  left join table_d as d USING (id) )
ORDER BY id, name IS NULL, subject IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks quite painful, but you should be able to do this with variables.  The idea is to enumerate the rows in each table (using variables).  Then combine all the rows together using `union all` and aggregate:

```
select id, max(name), max(state), max(subject), max(marks), max(sports), max(matches)
from ((select id, 1 as seqnum,
              null as name, null as state,
              null as subject, null as marks,
              null as sports, null as matches
       from a
      ) union all
      (select id, 
              (@rnb := if(@idb = id, @rnb + 1,
                          if(@idb := id, 1, 1)
                         )
              ),
              name, state, null, null, null, null
       from (select b.* from b order by id) b cross join
            (select @rnb := 0, @idb := -1) params
      ) union all
      (select id, 
              (@rnc := if(@idc = id, @rnc + 1,
                          if(@idc := id, 1, 1)
                         )
              ),
              null, null, subject, marks, null, null
       from (select c.* from c order by id) c cross join
            (select @rnc := 0, @idc := -1) params
      ) union all
      (select id, 
              (@rnd := if(@idd = id, @rnd + 1,
                          if(@idd := id, 1, 1)
                         )
              ),
              null, null, null, null, sports, matches
       from (select d.* from d order by id) d cross join
            (select @rnd := 0, @idd := -1) params
      )
     ) x
group by id, seqnum;
```